# Protobuf message exchange between plain TCP client & Netty Server using Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, protocol-buffers, netty

I am trying to create a TCP socket connection between a plain TCP client and Netty Server using Protobuf message exchange format in **Java** and it does not work. It works when I use Netty Client (instead of TCP client) & Netty Server.

At the **Netty Server** side, in ServerHandler class, I get the Object "msg" as type **"PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf"**. Now when I try to convert it to my custom Protobuf object it fails with error - 'java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf cannot be cast to class ProtoModel'.

```
public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter  {
---
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
---
```

**Client Side Code**

```
Socket clientConnection = new Socket("localhost",SERVER_PORT);
ObjectOutputStream outToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(clientConnection.getOutputStream());
ProtoModel.writeTo(outToServer); //ProtoModel is the protobuf class
```

I think it is something to do with Protobuf message encoding at TCP client end and decoding at Netty Server end. The same server code works when I use a Netty Client (as opposed to plain TCP Client).

**Netty Client Code**

```
EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).handler(new ClientInitializer());
Channel ch = bootstrap.connect("localhost",SERVER_PORT).sync().channel();
ChannelFuture lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(ProtoModel);
lastWriteFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

Please let me know if any other input is required from my end. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue. I am posting the solution below.

**Server Code**

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
            ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
            byte[] req = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
            buf.readBytes(req);
            ProtobufModel obj = ProtobufModel.parseFrom(ByteString.copyFrom(req));
}
```

The Object 'msg' is received as ByteBuf format in server end. Then 'ByteBuf' format needs to be converted to 'ByteString' and finally ProtobufModel can be retrieved from 'ByteString' format.

**Client Code**

```
SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel
                    .open(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), SERVER_PORT));
          ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
          byteBuffer.put(ProtobufModel.toByteArray());
          byteBuffer.flip();
          channel.write(byteBuffer);
```

At client end the ProtobufModel is converted to ByteBuffer and passed to server.